# Fitting n number of rectangles of n L & W into n number of probably Large Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have n number of rectangles(small ones) of n length and width and have n number big rectangles of n length and width. In short there is one list of rectangles to be fitted and another list of rectangles in which these rectangles will be fitted.

I am studying about various package fitting algorithms and I know various questions has been asked for the same but can't help me with this type of problem.

My question is how to optimally choose which big rectangle to choose first and how to fill small rectangles into it without being overlapped and minimum wastage area, until all the small rectangles are fitted in the big ones. It is OK, if the big rectangles are left unfilled when all the small rectangles are fitted.

Please help me where to start with and if the question doesn't give much clarity then please let me know. My purpose is to write an algorithm for the same problem.

Comment: Too broad for SO. You may want to search for "packing problem".

Comment: Optimally or just some "hopefully good" approximation?

Comment: Are the target rectangles of the same size?

Comment: @Codor No the target rectangles can be of both different sizes as well as same size.

Comment: @harold Optimally will be great but it will be good to start with "Hopefully good" approximation, so do you have any point from where I can start with ?

Comment: @Henry yes I know it is a broad question with n number of solutions, but I am just asking from where I can start and thanks for suggesting to look into "packing problem". I am currently digging into it and will get back if I find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in part, the problem under consideration is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) as it contains the [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem as a subproblem.